# Interval Estimation when $\overline{Y}$ and $S$ is unknown.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Question: A random sample of size $n=9$ is drawn from a normal distribution with $\mu=27.6$. Within what interval $(-a,+a)$ can we expect to find $\frac{\overline{Y}-27.6}{S/\sqrt{9}}$ $80$% of the time? $90$% of the time?

I have tried using $P(-t_{\frac{\alpha}{2},n-1} \leq \frac{\overline{Y}-27.6}{S/\sqrt{9}} \leq t_{\frac{\alpha}{2},n-1})=1-\alpha$. I therefore came up with $P(-1.397 \leq \frac{\overline{Y}-27.6}{S/\sqrt{9}}  \leq 1.397) =0.8$ (for the first part of the question asking about $80$% of the time. I do not, however, know what to do from here (or even if what I have done up to this point is correct) because I do not know that sample standard deviation, sample variance or $\overline{Y}$.

Comment: Aren't you done by putting $a=1.397$?

Comment: Do you think that I do not need to actually solve for an interval with a numerical answer? I guess that would make sense because the other values are not provided. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you're asked to find what interval $(-a,+a)$ we can expect to find $Z=\frac{\bar{Y}-27.6}{S/\sqrt{9}}$ $80\%$ of the time. It seems to me you have found that $P(-1.397\leq Z\leq 1.397)=0.8$ or in other words $P(Z\in (-1.397,1.397))=0.8$. So there is your $a$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find in what interval $(-a,+a)$ we can expect to find $$Z=\frac{\bar{Y}-27.6}{S/\sqrt{9}}$$ $80\%$ of the time.

It seems to me you have found that $P(-1.397\leq Z\leq 1.397)=0.8$ or in other words $P(Z\in (-1.397,1.397))=0.8$. So there is your $a$. -- [Stefan Hansen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336989/interval-estimation-when-overliney-and-s-is-unknown#comment726613_336989)